# Apollo Client return type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I am trying to build a simple function inside a class that returns an Apollo Client. Here is my code:

```
import appConfig from 'config/app-config';
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, createHttpLink } from '@apollo/client';
import LocalStorageKeys from 'constants/local-storage-keys';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

export class ApolloClientServiceImpl {
  private cache: InMemoryCache;
  constructor() {
    this.cache = new InMemoryCache();
  }

  createApolloClient(idToken: string): unknown {
    const httpLink = createHttpLink({
      uri: appConfig.hasura.url,
    });
    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
      let bearerToken = localStorage.getItem(LocalStorageKeys.TOKEN);
      if (idToken) {
        bearerToken = idToken;
      }
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: bearerToken ? `Bearer ${bearerToken}` : '',
        },
      };
    });
    return new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: this.cache,
    });
  }
}
```

My problem lies in the return type of the `createApolloClient` function. If I set it to `ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>` and in the return statement do something like this:

```
return new ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: this.cache,
    });
```

Then I get the following error:

```
Type 'InMemoryCache' is not assignable to type 'ApolloCache<InMemoryCache>'.
  Types of property 'restore' are incompatible.
    Type '(data: NormalizedCacheObject) => InMemoryCache' is not assignable to type '(serializedState: InMemoryCache) => ApolloCache<InMemoryCache>'.
      Types of parameters 'data' and 'serializedState' are incompatible.
        Type 'InMemoryCache' is not assignable to type 'NormalizedCacheObject'.
          Index signature is missing in type 'InMemoryCache'.ts(2322)
```

There is very little documentation about this topic on the Apollo client docs, thus my question is, what is the correct return type of this function?

EDIT: If I stay with only:

```
    return new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: this.cache,
    });
```

And change the return type to `ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>` then this fixes everything the error. Thanks to Alluan Hadad.

Comment: `new ApolloClient<InMemoryCache>` is bad. Should be `new ApolloClient`

Comment: @AluanHaddad turned out that this fixed the issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem. Specifying explicit type arguments, especially when there are values being passed, is an anti pattern. Correct typescript leverages type inference as much as possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

check out my class. The return type is `ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>`

```
import { InMemoryCache, NormalizedCacheObject } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";
import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { FragmentMatcher } from "apollo-client/core/LocalState";
import { ApolloLink } from "apollo-link";
import { onError } from "apollo-link-error";
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";

enum EApolloCLientCredentials {
    DEFAULT_OMIT = "omit",
    INCLUDE = "include",
    SAME_ORIGIN = "same-origin",
}

class ClsApolloClient {
    private _httpLink: HttpLink;
    private _credentials: EApolloCLientCredentials;
    private _fragmentMatcher: FragmentMatcher | undefined;
    private _graphqlServerUrl: string;
    private _cacheInMemoryRules: Record<string, any>;
    private _apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>;

    constructor(
        graphqlServerUrl: string,
        credentials: EApolloCLientCredentials = EApolloCLientCredentials.DEFAULT_OMIT,
        fragmentMatcher?: FragmentMatcher,
        cacheInMemoryRules: Record<string, any> = {}
    ) {
        this._graphqlServerUrl = graphqlServerUrl;
        this._credentials = credentials;
        this._fragmentMatcher = fragmentMatcher;
        this._cacheInMemoryRules = cacheInMemoryRules;

        this._apolloClient = this.initApolloClient();
    }

    get apolloClient(): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
        return this._apolloClient;
    }

    get httpLink(): HttpLink {
        return this._httpLink;
    }

    get cacheInMemoryRules(): Record<string, any> {
        return this._cacheInMemoryRules;
    }
    set cacheInMemoryRules(cacheInMemoryRules: Record<string, any>) {
        this._cacheInMemoryRules = cacheInMemoryRules;
        this._apolloClient = this.initApolloClient();
    }

    get credentials(): EApolloCLientCredentials {
        return this._credentials;
    }

    set credentials(credentials: EApolloCLientCredentials) {
        this._credentials = credentials;
        this._apolloClient = this.initApolloClient();
    }

    get fragmentMatcher(): FragmentMatcher | undefined {
        return this._fragmentMatcher;
    }

    set fragmentMatcher(fragmentMatcher: FragmentMatcher | undefined) {
        this._fragmentMatcher = fragmentMatcher;
        this._apolloClient = this.initApolloClient();
    }

    private initApolloClient(): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
        const errorLink = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
            if (graphQLErrors)
                graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
                    console.log(
                        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
                    )
                );

            if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
        });

        this._httpLink = new HttpLink({
            uri: this._graphqlServerUrl,
            credentials: this._credentials,
        });
        const links = [errorLink, this._httpLink];
        const apolloClient: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> = new ApolloClient(
            {
                link: ApolloLink.from(links),
                cache: new InMemoryCache({
                    ...this._cacheInMemoryRules,
                    addTypename: false,
                }),
                fragmentMatcher: this._fragmentMatcher,
            }
        );
        return apolloClient;
    }
}

export { EApolloCLientCredentials, ClsApolloClient };
```